# SSAS IsAggregatable for Currency Dimensions

Tags: ssas, currency, dimension

I have a cube with a Source Currency Dimension and a Billing Currency Dimension. I set both of these to IsAggregatable = False (which seems to be recommended since I don't want an All level to automatically sum up over different currencies!). When the All level is taken away I am left with a single default currency, that I can set if I want.

Problem is the two dimensions now act as a sort of filter to each other. If I want a total of all Billing Amounts by billing currency and drag that dimension on its own onto the grid, the result is filtered to show only the transactions (if any) that also match the default Source Currency. And vica versa. It is only if I drag the other dimension onto the grid that I have the ability to show all the data.

Is there some setting that allows a default member of a dimension to represent all the members? It feels like Not Aggregatable makes sense in the context of that one dimension, but seems to make little sense in the context of other dimensions in terms of seeing all data. Ie I want to see a summary of transactions by Billing Currency - and I DON'T CARE what the source currency was (ie you can consider All of them).

I am quite likely falling into some basic trap here, possibly design related - any clues would be appreciated.

Glenn

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a reference to an article that describes this situation EXACTLY, and an interesting approach to resolving it. The main thing for me was recognition that the situation is real and not an issue with my design.

[Issue described and resolved here](http://dlaplante.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/ssas-summing-on-different-currencies-dont-hide-your-data/)

Comment: I was tackling exactly the same problem, this entry and blog helped me a ton, thank you!